# A problem in functions of a complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $n+1$ real numbers $a_0,a_1,\cdots, a_{n}$ such that $0<a_0<\cdots<a_n$. Let $P(z)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^n a_i z^i $, where $z\in \mathbb{C}$. How to show that there must be $n$ roots of $P(z)$ in $\mid z\mid<1$?  Thank you very much!

Comment: This is a variant form of Enestrom-Kakeya theorem.

Comment: Get it! Thank you very much! @ ts375_zk26 @  copper.hat